# Black area on object

Tags: modeling

[image]

hi, I connected this red part and blue part with <kbd>F</kbd> and it seems like it's filled but there's black part between...
Is there something wrong with this?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: can you share your file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=96ZgM2bP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/96ZgM2bP/)

Comment: Check under Overlays > "Normal Orientation"  ... you have switched normal direction in red part.

Comment: @vklidu why not post it as answer? :)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Sorry ... On this site is hundreds Q with this issue ... I'm just lazy to search for one and vote close as duplicates Q.:)

Comment: true story bro 